# Distribution of compound Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose a compound Poisson process is defined as $X_{t} = \sum_{n=1}^{N_t} Y_n$, where $\{Y_n\}$ are i.i.d. with some distribution $F_Y$, and $(N_t)$ is a Poisson process with parameter $\alpha$ and also independent from $\{Y_n\}$.

1. Is it true that as 
   $t\rightarrow \infty, \, \frac{X_{t}-E(X_{t})}{\sigma(X_t)
       \sqrt(N_t)}  \rightarrow \mathbf{N}(0, 1)$ in distribution, where the limit is a standard Gaussian distribution? I am considering
   using Central Limit Theorem to show it, but the
   theorem I have learned only applies when $N_t$ is
   fixed and deterministic instead of
   being a Poisson process.
2. A side question: is it possible to derive the
   distribution of $X_{t}$, for each $t\geq 0$? Some book that has the derivation?

Thanks!

Comment: @Shai: Sources: http://books.google.com/books?id=4hfNyLXb6M8C&pg=PA140&dq=%22compound+poisson+process%22++normal+distribution++central+limit+theorem&hl=en&ei=tHOcTZf0MM-atwfQoK3BBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22compound%20poisson%20process%22%20%20normal%20distribution%20%20central%20limit%20theorem&f=false and http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110208135141AAoP4ZO . In the former, it does not claim the convergence, but in the latter, it claims it when the state space of $(X_t)$ is finite. I think I should consider the restricted case.

Comment: The denominator in your expression in question 1 is not right. You want either $\sigma(X_t)$ or a multiple of $\sqrt{N_t}$, not both multiplied together. In your first reference, they divide by $\sigma \sqrt{M}$; the correct analogy in your problem is $\sigma(Y) \sqrt{N_t}$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $Y(j)$ be i.i.d. with finite mean and variance, and set 
$\mu=\mathbb{E}(Y)$ and $\tau=\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Y^2)}$. 
If $(N(t))$ is an independent Poisson process with rate $\lambda$,
then the compound Poisson process is defined as 
$$X(t)=\sum_{j=0}^{N(t)} Y(j).$$

The characteristic function of $X(t)$ is calculated as follows:
for real $s$ we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\psi(s)&=&\mathbb{E}\left(e^{is X(t)}\right)\cr
       &=&\sum_{j=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}\left(e^{is X(t)} \ | \ N(t)=j\right) \mathbb{P}(N(t)=j)\cr
       &=&\sum_{j=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}\left(e^{is (Y(1)+\cdots +Y(j))} \ | \ N(t)=j\right) \mathbb{P}(N(t)=j)\cr 
       &=&\sum_{j=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}\left(e^{is (Y(1)+\cdots +Y(j))}\right) \mathbb{P}(N(t)=j)\cr
       &=&\sum_{j=0}^\infty \phi_Y(s)^j {(\lambda t)^j\over j!} e^{-\lambda t}\cr
       &=& \exp(\lambda t [\phi_Y(s)-1])
       \end{eqnarray*}
where $\phi_Y$ is the characteristic function of $Y$.

From this we easily calculate $\mu(t):=\mathbb{E}(X(t))=\lambda t \mu$ 
and $\sigma(t):=\sigma(X(t))= \sqrt{\lambda t} \tau$.

Take the expansion $\phi_Y(s)=1+is\mu -s^2\tau^2 /2+o(s^2)$ and substitute it into 
the characteristic function of the normalized random variable  ${(X(t)-\mu(t)) /\sigma(t)}$ to obtain

\begin{eqnarray*}
\psi^*(s) &=& \exp(-is(\mu(t)/\sigma(t))) \exp(\lambda t [\phi_Y(s/\sigma(t))-1]) \
       &=& \exp(-s^2/2 +o(1))
\end{eqnarray*}
where $o(1)$ goes to zero as $t\to\infty$. This gives the central limit theorem
$${X(t)-\mu(t)\over\sigma(t)}\Rightarrow N(0,1).$$

We may replace $\sigma(t)$, for example, with $\tau \sqrt{N(t)}$ to get
$${X(t)-\mu(t)\over\tau \sqrt{N(t)}}= {X(t)-\mu(t)\over\sigma(t)} \sqrt{\lambda t \over N(t)} \Rightarrow N(0,1),$$
by [Slutsky's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem), since  $\sqrt{\lambda t \over N(t)}\to 1$ in probability by the law of large numbers.

---

**Added:** Let $\sigma=\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Y^2)-\mathbb{E}(Y)^2}$ be the standard deviation of $Y$,
and define the sequence of standardized random variables 
$$T(n)={\sum_{j=1}^n Y(j) -n\mu\over\sigma\sqrt{n}},$$
so that 
$${X(t)-\mu N(t)\over \sigma \sqrt{N(t)}}=T(N(t)).$$

Let $f$ be a bounded, continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$. By the usual
central limit theorem we have $\mathbb{E}(f(T(n)))\to \mathbb{E}(f(Z))$ where
 $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.

We have for any $N>1$,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
|\mathbb{E}(f(T(N(t)))) - \mathbb{E}(f(Z))|
  &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty |\mathbb{E}(f(T(n)) - \mathbb{E}(f(Z))|\ \mathbb{P}(N(t)=n)  \cr
  &\leq& 2\|f\|_\infty \mathbb{P}(N(t)\leq N) +\sup_{n>N} |\mathbb{E}(f(T(n)))- \mathbb{E}(f(Z)) |.
\end{eqnarray*} 
$$
First choosing $N$ large to make the right hand side small, then letting $t\to\infty$ so
that $\mathbb{P}(N(t)\leq N)\to 0$, shows that 
$$  \mathbb{E}(f(T(N(t)))) \to \mathbb{E}(f(Z)). $$
This shows that $T(N(t))$ converges in distribution to a standard normal as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: @Byron: Thanks! Let me try to understand your reply. There are two different ratios here, and you have shown the first ratio converges in distribution, while you are working on the second one?

Comment: @Ethan You're welcome! Actually I have three ratios. I've shown that the first two converge to $N(0,1)$ and I'm sure that the third one converges to a normal distribution with some other variance. But I haven't checked the details yet.

Comment: @Byron: Thanks! (1) About "the expansion $\phi_Y(s)=1+is\mu -s^2\tau^2 /2+o(s^2)$", I seem to have seen this in Kailai Chung's A course in probability theory, but now cannot find it. Do you know where I can find some explanation about the expansion of the characteristic function? (2) Is "the cardinality of the state space of $(X_t)$ is finite" required for the three ratios to converge to N(0,1)?

Comment: @Ethan (1) I don't have that book of Chung, but this expansion can be found in many probability texts. For instance, it is Theorem 3.8 (section 2.3) in Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples (2nd edition)* and Theorem 4 in section 5.7 of Grimmett and Stirzaker's *Probability and Random Processes (3rd edition)*. As for point (2), we make no assumption on the state space of $X(t)$. We only need the $Y$ random variables to have finite variance.

Comment: @Ethan: Kai Lai Chung.

Comment: @Byron: Re the end of your post, conditioning is unnecessary here. Rather, note that $X(t)-\mu N(t)=\bar X(t)$, where $\bar X$ is based on the random variables $\bar Y(j)=Y(j)-\mu$ like $X$ is based on the random variables $Y(j)$. Since $\bar\sigma(t)=\sigma(t)$, your first result yields $(X(t)-\mu N(t))/\sigma(t)\implies N(0,1)$. And $N(t)/t\to\lambda$ almost surely, hence $(X(t)-\mu N(t))/(\tau\sqrt{N(t)})\implies N(0,1)$.

Comment: @Didier In my first result, I subtracted the non-random 
$\mathbb{E}(X(t))$, not the random variable $\mu N(t)$. So I'm not sure it applies here.

Comment: @Byron: It does. Here you substract the non-random $E(\bar X(t))=0$ to $\bar X(t)$.

Comment: @Didier Ah, quite right. That was stupid of me. I'll leave the conditioning argument up anyway. Plus, there is the small chance of division by zero that I've ignored, but I think I'll stop here.

Comment: @Didier Actually, $\bar\sigma(t)\neq \sigma(t)$ which is why you should normalize with $\tau$ in one case, and with $\sigma$ in the other. But your idea is right!

Comment: @Byron: Right, $\bar\sigma(t)=\sqrt{\lambda t}\bar\tau$ and $\bar\tau=\sqrt{E(\bar Y^2)}=\sigma$ hence $\bar\sigma(t)=\sqrt{\lambda t}\sigma$ while $\sigma(t)=\sqrt{\lambda t}\tau$. Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Derivation of the formula for the distribution of $X_t$. The formula 
$$
P_{X_t }  = e^{ - t\nu (\mathbb{R})} \sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^\infty  {(k!)^{ - 1} t^k \nu ^k } ,
$$
where $\nu$ is the L\'evy measure of $X$ and $\nu^k$ is the $k$-fold convolution of $\nu$, is very easy to derive. Indeed, using the notation in the question, the law of total probability gives
$$
{\rm P}(X_t  \in B) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{\rm P}(X_t  \in B|N_t  = k){\rm P}(N_t  = k)} .
$$
Thus,
$$
{\rm P}(X_t  \in B) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{\rm P}(Y_1  +  \cdots  + Y_k  \in B)\frac{{e^{ - \alpha t} (\alpha t)^k }}{{k!}}}  = e^{ - \alpha t} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {(k!)^{ - 1} t^k \alpha ^k F_Y^k (B) } ,
$$
where $F_Y^k$ is the $k$-fold convolution of $F_Y$. Now, since the corresponding L\'evy measure $\nu$ is given by $\nu (dx) = \alpha F_Y (dx)$, it holds $\nu(\mathbb{R}) = \alpha$ and $\nu^k = \alpha^k F_Y ^k$, and so the original formula is established.

Remark. As should be clear, the distribution of $X_t$ is very complicated in general.

Answer (score 4):

The distribution of $X_t$ is given by
$$
P_{X_t }  = e^{ - t\nu (\mathbb{R})} \sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^\infty  {(k!)^{ - 1} t^k \nu ^k } ,
$$
where $\nu$ is the L\'evy measure of $X$, and $\nu^k$ is the $k$-fold convolution of $\nu$. This is contained in Remark 27.3 in the book [L\'evy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions], by Sato.

For a compound Poisson process with rate $\alpha$ and jump distribution $F_Y$, the L\'evy measure $\nu$ is finite and given by $\nu(dx)=\alpha F_Y (dx)$.

EDIT:

For the first question, note that if $t =n \in \mathbb{N}$, then
$$
X_t = X_n = (X_1 - X_0) + (X_2 - X_1) + \cdots + (X_n - X_{n-1})
$$
(note that $X_0 = 0$). Thus, $X_t$ is a sum of $n$ i.i.d. variables, each with expectation ${\rm E}(X_1)$ and variance ${\rm Var}(X_1)$. Now, as is well known and easy to show,
$$
{\rm E}(X_1) = \alpha {\rm E}(Y_1) = \alpha \int {xF_Y (dx)} 
$$
and
$$
{\rm Var}(X_1) = \alpha {\rm E}(Y_1^2) = \alpha \int {x^2 F_Y (dx)}, 
$$
provided that $Y_1$ has finite second moment. Thus, by the central limit theorem,
$$
\frac{{X_t  - n\alpha {\rm E}(Y_1 )}}{{\sqrt {\alpha {\rm E}(Y_1^2 )} \sqrt n }} \to {\rm N}(0,1),
$$
as $n \to \infty$.

EDIT: Put it another way,
$$
\frac{{X_t  - {\rm E}(X_t )}}{{\sqrt {{\rm Var}(X_t )} }} \to {\rm N}(0,1)
$$
(shown here for the case $t \to \infty$ integer).

EDIT: Some more details in response to the OP's request.

A compound Poisson process is a special case of a L\'evy process, that is, a process $X=\{X_t: t \geq 0\}$ with stationary independent increments, continuous in probability and having sample paths which are right-continuous with left limits, and starting at $0$. In particular, for any $t \geq 0$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $X_t$ can be decomposed as a sum of $n$ i.i.d. random variables, which means that $X_t$ is infinitely divisible. There is a vast literature available online on this important topic.

Comment: @Ethan: What do you mean by "Also same question except by using the distribution given by the book by Sato?"

Comment: @Shai: I meant if one could show the convergence, respectively by using Central limit theorem, and by the distribution of $X_t$ from the book you cited.

Comment: @Ethan: Only by using CLT...

Comment: @Shai: Thanks! I was wondering why "$X_t$ is a sum of n i.i.d. variables", i.e. why those increments of compound Poisson process are i.i.d.?

Comment: @Ethan: Indeed.

Comment: @Shai: Thanks! Are there some books which explain that?

Comment: @Ethan: I'll elaborate on this later on.

Comment: @Shai: Thanks! Another question: Is "the cardinality of the state space of $(X_t)$ is finite" required for the ratio to converge to N(0,1)?

Comment: @Ethan: No, but what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @Shai: The condition means that there are finitely many values that $X_t$ can take, just same as in the problem in the Yahoo link http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110208135141AAoP4ZO .

Comment: @Ethan: That condition talks about the $Y_i$ (in your question), but is not required.

Comment: @Shai: Thanks! So in your first edit, the last expression means you have shown that for natural number n, as n goes to infinity, the ratio converges in distribution to N(0,1). If I want to further show that as real number t goes to infinity, the ratio converges to N(0,1), is it because sequential continuity and continuity of distribution functions are equivalent?

Comment: @Ethan: For the general case, you should consider an arbitrary sequence $t_n$ of real numbers tending to $\infty$ (rather than just $t_n = n$).

Comment: So, I suggest decomposing $X_t$ as $X_t = X_n + (X_t - X_n)$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Shai: Thanks! With that decomposition, the increments are independent instead of being i.i.d.. I was wondering which version of CLT is easy for use to show the convergence?

Comment: @Ethan: Elaborating on that suggestion: Consider the decomposition $\frac{{X_t  - E(X_t )}}{{\sigma (X_t )}} = \frac{{X_n  - E(X_n )}}{{\sigma (X_n )}}\frac{{\sigma (X_n )}}{{\sigma (X_t )}} + \xi (n,t)$, where $\xi(n,t)$ is independent of the left term. Try showing that $\xi(n,t)$ converges to $0$ in probability, and hence also in distribution.