# Feynmann-Kac representation for Compound Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, heat-equation, poisson-process, levy-processes

**Heat equation with brownian motion**

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcr}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}       &= &   \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}  \\
u(x,0) & = & \phi(x) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

admits as solution $ \mathbb{E}[ \phi(x+ X_t)]$

**Heat equation for Poisson Process**

We want to show an equivalent of the [Heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) expressed with a Brownian motion,  for a Poisson process.

- $ (P_t)_{ t \geq 0}$ is a Poisson process of intensity $\lambda$
- $(Z_n)_n$ are iid with distribution $ \nu(dz)$ on $\mathbb {R}$
- $Y_t =\sum_{k=1}^{P_t} Z_k$  It is a  [Compound Poisson process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31329/distribution-of-compound-poisson-process?rq=1)
- $u : [0,T] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$ on $[0,T] \times \mathbb {R}  $ with bounded derivatives.
- initial condition $u(0,x) = g(x)$
- 

$$   \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}  = \int_{ \mathbb{R} } \left( u(t,x+z)- u(t,x) \right) \lambda \nu(dz)                $$

- We fix $t \in [0,T]$ and $ x \in \mathbb{R}$

We want to show that

$$ \boxed{ u(t,x)= \mathbb{E} g(x+Y_t) }$$

1. Show that there is a random Poisson measure $N$ such that $Y_t= \int_{\mathbb{R}  } z N(dr,dz)$
2. 

- $\tilde{N}$ is the compensated Poisson measure.
- $Z_t= \int_{0}^t \int_{\mathbb{R}  } 
  [ u(t-r, x + Y_r +z) - u(t-r, x +Y_r)] \tilde{N} (dr, dz)
  $
- Prove that the process $Z_t$ is integrable and with null expectation.

3. Show that $u(t,x)= \mathbb{E} g(x+Y_t)$. Apply Ito formula to $(r,y) \mapsto u(t-r,y)$ and Levy process $ (r, x+ Y_r)$

---

1. 

\begin{align*}
 Y_t &=&  \sum_{0 < s \leq t}  \Delta Y_s \\
 &=&  \int_{0}^t  z J_Y(dr,dz) \\ 
\end{align*}

$J_Y$ is the Poisson random measure of the jumps, andhas for intensity $ \rho(dt \times dx) = \lambda dt \nu(dx)$

2. According to *Financial modelling with jump processes* , proposition 2.16,

- $A_t= \int_{0}^t  \int_{ \mathbb{R} } f(s,y) \tilde N(ds,dy)$ is a martingale
- if $ \mu(f)= \int_{0}^t  \int_{ \mathbb{R} }  |f(s,y) |\rho(dt \times dx) < \infty $

Or we may just use that $u$ has bounded derivatives.

$
\begin{align*}
Z_t &=& \int_0^t  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} (t-r, x+ Y_r) dr \\
|Z_t|  &\leq &   \int_0^t  | \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} (t-r, x+ Y_r) | dr \\
|Z_t| &\leq & K t \\
|Z_t| &\leq  &K T
\end{align*}
$

The question seems closed to this [one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140139/feynman-kac-for-jump-diffusion) and to this [article](https://www.eurandom.tue.nl/reports/2000/032-report.pdf), equation (10).

3. The Ito formula for Jump processes is given in this [online course page 69 and 70 theorem 6.4](http://perso.univ-lemans.fr/%7Eapopier/enseignement/ENSTA/poly_ENSTA_proc_levy.pdf) and in *Financial modelling with jump processes* proposition 8.18

We follow the hint and consider $ (r,y) \mapsto u(t-r,y)$ and the Levy process $(r,x+Y_r)$

$\begin{align*}
f(s,Y_s) &=u(s,x+Y_s) \\
f(s,Y_s) - f(0,X_0) &= \int_{0}^{s} \frac{ \partial f } { \partial w } (w,Y_w) dw + \int_{0}^{s}\frac{ \partial f } { \partial y_1 }  (w, Y_{w-}) dY_w  + \sum_{0<w \leq t} \left[ f(w,Y_w) -f(w,Y_{w-}) - \Delta Y_s 
\frac{ \partial f } { \partial y_1 }(w,Y_w-) \right]
\\
u(s,x+Y_s) -u(t,0) &= - \int_{0}^t \frac{ \partial u } { \partial t}u(w,Y_w-) +\int_{0}^{s}\frac{ \partial u } { \partial x }  (w, x+Y_{w-}) dY_w + \sum_{0<w \leq t} \left[ u(w,x+Y_w) -u(w,x+Y_{w-}) - \Delta Y_s 
\frac{ \partial u } { \partial x }(w,Y_{   {w^-} +x   }) \right]
\end{align*}
$

I hope the derivative of the composite function is correct. And
$ \sum_{0<w \leq t}\Delta Y_s 
\frac{ \partial u } { \partial x }(w,Y_w+x) = \int_{0<w \leq t} \frac{ \partial u } { \partial x }(w,Y_{ {w^-}}+x) dY_w$

so we should have one cancellation of term ,and the rest should look like the martingale in the previous question.

Comment: Seems like you are dealing with a Markov process. What about invoking Kolmogorov's equations?

Comment: Thanks, I may have a found a useful formula.

Comment: Do you know how to apply  the Ito formula for the last question ?

Comment: do you know the Ito formula for jump processes?

Comment: Yes, I know the formula, and I am not sure how to apply it in this case.

Comment: Would you mind putting it here and explaining, what aren't you sure about?

Comment: Ok, I have written the next step. Thanks for reading.

Comment: There is no stochastic PDE in this question.